# Convert retrieved Blob to base64 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, base64, byte, blob

I am trying to read blob from oracle database and convert it to base64String then display it in my web page. Reading from oracle is working fine and is returning data, but converting image to base64 is returning huge value (length = 1 600 000 and above) that cannot be converted to image and displayed in my page (a broken icon image is displayed). In other words I implemented a base64String from the internet in my code and everything works properly ... what is the best way to convert my blobs to images ? Below is my code:

```
 Dim Conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connString").ConnectionString
        Dim cnnConnection As New OracleConnection(Conn)
        cnnConnection.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cnnConnection
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT d.document_file from T_library_documents d d.library_documents_id=64 ORDER BY d.DOCUMENT_NAME"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read() Then

            Dim blob As OracleBlob = dr.GetOracleBlob(0)
            Dim byteArr As [Byte]() = New [Byte](blob.Length - 1) {}
            Dim i As Integer = blob.Read(byteArr, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(blob.Length))
            blob.Close()
            cnnConnection.Close()

            Dim imageBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr)
            Dim imageSrc As String = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64)
            img.Attributes("src") = imageSrc
        End If
```

Comment: How long is the `Byte` array?

Comment: In this case byteArr.length= 1 581 052

Comment: Can you confirm that the img src attribute is actually getting the byte array on the page ?

Comment: Absolutly, in debugging mode I can see the src is getting the exact value that I want, and I tried to take imageBase64 and implement it in an online converter but it failed  http://jsfiddle.net/SXFwP/ @Karlta05

Comment: Ok. You are aware that your datatype is different. data:image/gif vs data:image/png

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, even with jpg @Karlta05

Comment: on the actual page, if you inspect the element, is the data there?

Comment: Yes and the src is filled correctly @Karlta05